# How to apply two 'match' rules inside an xsl:template for a parent and child nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, xforms

I have the following basic xml file:

```
<structure>
   <part class="Button" id="b1">
        <style>
            <property name="label">Click me!</property>
        </style>
   </part>
</structure>
```

And I am applying XSL to transform this into a html layout with an XForms button/eventually event as well. My xsl:template is the following:

```
<xsl:template match="part[@class='Button']">
    <xforms:trigger>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@accesskey | @tabindex | @size | @style | @id"/>
        <xforms:label>
            <xsl:value-of select="@label"/>
        </xforms:label>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@onclick"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xforms:trigger>
</xsl:template>
```

Ideally, I want the xforms:label to be take the text "Click me!" and disregard the style tag from the xml. 
So the final result should be:

```
<xforms:trigger id="b1">
    <xforms:label>Click me!</xf:label>
</xforms:trigger>
```

How do I get there? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

here is a new example of the another possible scenario of the `style` tag:

```
<structure>
   <part class="Button" id="b1"/>            
</structure>
<style>
   <property part-name="b1" name='label'>Click me!</property>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To obtain the result you are expecting your template can be much simpler:

```
<xsl:template match="part[@class='Button']">
    <xforms:trigger id="{@id}">
        <xforms:label>
            <xsl:value-of select="style/property[@name='label']"/>
        </xforms:label>
    </xforms:trigger>
</xsl:template>
```

Since your template uses the context created by `part`, the path from that context to `property` is `style/property`. You could also have used less efficient paths like `.//property`, `*/property`. The `id` was copied using [Attribute Value Templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates).

As for your other `<xsl:apply-templates>` they seem meaningless unless your code is much different than the one you included in the question. The last one will actually add all child elements to the `trigger` which doesn't seem to be what you want.

**UPDATE** To deal with your second scenario as well, I'll consider you have an input XML such as the one below, with some buttons with nested styles and others that refer to a style which is elsewhere in the document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<structure>
    <style>
        <property part-name="b2" name="label">Click me NOT!</property>
        <property part-name="b1" name="label">Click me!</property>
    </style>
    <part class="Button" id="b1"/>
    <part class="Button" id="b3"/>
    <part class="Button" id="b4">
        <style>
            <property name="label">Click me!</property>
        </style>
    </part>
</structure>
```

To refer to the properties in the `<style>` block we can create a map selectable by a key, which would be the `@part-name`. When you retrieve the element passing the button's ID as a *key*, you will get the corresponding `property`. This line sets up such a map called `labels`. It will return a `<property>` element which has a `name` attribute with the value `label` when called with the value of its `part-name` attribute:

```
<xsl:key name="labels" match="property[@name='label']" use="@part-name"/>
```

This template will generate the code you want for `<part>` elements that are `Button` if an element exists in the `labels` map that has a key equal to its `@id`. It will then retrieve that element and use its value:

```
<xsl:template match="part[@class='Button'][key('labels', @id)]">
    <xforms:trigger id="{@id}">
        <xforms:label>
            <xsl:value-of select="key('labels', @id)"/>
        </xforms:label>
    </xforms:trigger>
</xsl:template>
```

This is the full stylesheet which deals with an instance that may contain both scenarios (such as the one listed above):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xforms="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms" version="1.0">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <!-- Map containing all property[@name='label'] using by their @part-name as key -->
    <xsl:key name="labels" match="property[@name='label']" use="@part-name"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="structure/part"/>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- All <part> elements that do not match the other two templates -->
    <xsl:template match="part"/>

    <!-- Buttons which have an @id corresponding to a style/property @part-name -->
    <xsl:template match="part[@class='Button'][key('labels', @id)]">
        <xforms:trigger id="{@id}">
            <xforms:label>
                <xsl:value-of select="key('labels', @id)"/>
            </xforms:label>
        </xforms:trigger>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Buttons which have a nested style/property with @name=label -->
    <xsl:template match="part[@class='Button'][style/property[@name='label']]">
        <xforms:trigger id="{@id}">
            <xforms:label>
                <xsl:value-of select="style/property[@name='label']"/>
            </xforms:label>
        </xforms:trigger>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With that data it will generate this result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns:xforms="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms">
   <xforms:trigger id="b1">
      <xforms:label>Click me!</xforms:label>
   </xforms:trigger>
   <xforms:trigger id="b4">
      <xforms:label>Click me!</xforms:label>
   </xforms:trigger>
</root>
```

You can see it working and test the results in this **[XSLT Fiddle](http://xsltransform.net/nc4NzPU)**

Comment: Thanks, that did it - I need to refresh some XPath simple concepts obviously... My template is longer, due to some additional cases where the part element can contain some additional properties.

Comment: Yes, I removed the `<xsl:apply-templates>`. Thanks!

Comment: Instead of a new question, would it be possible to match `style` tag if it is not a child of `part` tag? For example the `style` tag could look like that: `<style> <property part-name="b1" name="label">Click me!</property> </style>` - and the `part-name` is used to match the concrete `style` with the correct `part`. I guess I need some sort of a 'where' statement or?

Comment: Yes. You can match any element. You could use `<xsl:template match="style[property/@part-name='b1']">` to match the `style` elements which have a `property` child with the `part-name` attribute containing `b1`.

Comment: Sure, but I am struggling to make it generic - I won;t always know what the ids literals will be, but I'd like to match them when they are the same (when `part-name` == `id` from `part`).

Comment: Oh, I understand now. `part[@class='Button'][property/@part-name=@id]` will match the parts that have a `Button` class and which have a child `property` with a `part-name` attribute equal to the part's `id` attribute.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not sure how that can possibly work :) I will fire up another question to get more traction/attention.

Comment: I meant `<xsl:template match="part[@class='Button'][style/property/@part-name=@id]">` (I forgot that `property` is not a child of `part`, but `style` is)

Comment: I guess a bit of miss communication occurred :) - `style` is now not child of `part`. I made an edit to the post adding an xml example.